# Federating multiple Fuseki endpoints - authentication

Tags: authentication, sparql, jena, fuseki, federated-queries

We are running multiple fuseki servers. We want to run Sparql queries using data from any number of them. That means using the SERVICE key word, no problem.

How do we set up authentication in Fuseki server A to access Fuseki server B?

Presumably it is done using a service .ttl file, but after waterboarding google for an hour it still won't give an straight answer.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/service.html) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28829913/7879193) (sorry, I have no detailed solution).

Comment: Thanks Stanislav. That is the kind of info I have been finding, but I can't work out from that the approach.